# nearest point in postgres tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need some help in finding nearest points of each entry of a particular table to another if and only if the nearest entry comes within 10 miles.

2 tables are here:

```
Table A
lon | lat | block_id
```

and

```
table B
 city        | latitude | longitude | block_id
-------------------+----------+-----------+----------
```

Now, I have to update blockid of table A with the one of Table B which is closest to that entry and if within 10 miles. If no match found, maybe update it "NA". Table A consists of a million entries, table B 10 entries.

I am working with postgres 9.4. I am quite new to postgres, hence not very comfortable in it although fairly comfortable with sql.

Please bear with me if any mistakes. Thanks a lot for your help, I am stuck bad.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Have you installed postgis extension?

Comment: yes, just checked  
 POSTGIS="2.3.3

Comment: Then [**this**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/how-operator-work) one may help. You convert lon, lat to point create a spatial index and then you can use `<->` operator for fast searchs

Comment: I understand I can get geom by ST_point(lon, lat) and to get the distance I can ST_distance(geom1, geom2), I checked up the link, i guess its not much helpful, close, but somehow not able to figure out much, also, I think sird should be 4326, so in other words, I am a bit confused, can you please help in giving any other link in pointing out related query or help in formulating one.... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you create a field column `geom` with  geometry type? update using ST_point.

Then you do

```
with cte as (
      SELECT A.geom, B.geom, B.block_id,
             ST_Distance(A.geom, B.geom) as dist -- check this value first
      FROM TableA as A
      CROSS JOIN TableB as B
      WHERE ST_Distance(A.geom, B.geom) < 16000 -- 10 miles
)
SELECT *
FROM  cte
```

EDIT:

Lets assume your CTE works, then you can find the nearest point like this

```
with cte as (
  ....
), sort as (
   SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by A.id order by dist) as  rn
   FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM sort 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Create an Indexing on a 'location' field, and the location field has a point data type.

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name USING GIST(location);
```

GiST index is capable of optimizing “nearest-neighbor” search :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY location <-> point '(-74.013, 40.711)' LIMIT 10;
```

**Note:** The point first element is longitude and the second element is latitude.